# loop through all anchor tags of html page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to refrence all anchore tags on page that have

```
<body>
    <h1>not me</h1>
    <a href ="google.com"></a>
    <h1>not me also </h1>
    <a href ="fb.com"></a>

    <h2>me also as i am H2 </h2>
    <a href ="FIDDLE.com"></a>
    <h3>not me also </h3>
    <a href ="fbO.com"></a>
    <h2>me also as i am H2 </h2>
    <a href ="FIDDLE2.com"></a>

    <button onclick="score2Dmatrix();" id="btn" ></button>
```

**h2** tag as their parent using jquery , for that i have to pass through each anchor tag that have parent **h2** and then add attribute

```
onclick="callme();";
```

i am using that code onclick

```
<script>      
function callme() {
    $("h2 a").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "score2Dmatrix();");
    });
};
</script>
```

but no effort
link to fiddle is this  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nouman_nomi3T/dmnxkfhm/7/)

**thanks for that tobby answers is right**

```
selector(h2 + a)...
```

Comment: First thing in your fiddle <h2> is not parent of anchor ( <a> ). Please specify question correctly.

Comment: all `h2` in your html are siblings of `a` not parent

Comment: now check every thing os their

Comment: Toby Flemming answer should serve you well. To add attr to a element using jquery check below link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Comment: on button click i want to loop through all anchor tags of page not specific click of anchore tag'

Comment: you dont have to explicitly loop thru all the elements using for loop, thats what selectors are for $('h2 a') will find all the a with h2 as their parent.

Comment: now check please latest fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nouman_nomi3T/dmnxkfhm/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: https://jsbin.com/towejoqudu/edit?html,js,console,output

I have added text into your anchors so you can actually click them.

Comment: The point of stackoverflow is to learn, not to find someone to do your work for you. Asking someone who has provided the correct answer to also rewrite your code is not in the spirit of this website.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this please?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this selection donot work i checked in debugging mode

Comment: when i asked about learning you peoples say that we give solution not learning for learning their are other sites this is a problem in my project where i stuck i want to get all anchore tags with heading `h2` you `h2 a` not work in console also

Comment: you want to get all anchor tags inside h2 or next to h2 ?

Comment: `h2 + a` this one i need

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h2').find('a').on('click', callme);
```

You can avoid all of the unnecessary traversal by binding to the body once (event delegation), like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var $clicked = $(this);
    if($clicked.closest('h2').length){
        callme();
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to add on `onclick="callme();"`  in all anchore tags have `h2` as header see fiddle modify that